# Facebook share does not display large thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, facebook, open-graph-protocol

I'm trying to share posts from my WordPress blog on Facebook. I want them to show in the new format with large thumbnails.

Here's is what I'm using:

```
<meta property='og:site_name' content='<?php wp_title(''); ?>'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='turmtheater:vorstellung' />
<meta property='og:title' content='mytitle' />
<meta property='og:url' content='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' />
<meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo get_img_url(); ?>' />
```

The image-URL is definitely correct and points to a large image (1400 * 650 or something like that). But Facebook still re-sizes the image to the old 116*116 format.

Shouldn't it work if `og:image` is given, or is there anything else needed?

Edit: If I repost the link from my facebook wall, the repostet link shows the large image. So Facebook definitely uses the right one. It just displays as a small post.

Comment: What does it say in Facebook Debugger? Is it properly marked or does it has errors?

Comment: The Debugger says, it's correct it even shows me the big image: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.regensburgerturmtheater.de%2Fmei-faehr-lady%2F

Comment: I see a 142px x 142px <meta property='og:image' content='http://www.regensburgerturmtheater.de/wp-content/uploads/Fröhliche-Wissenschaft.jpg' />

Comment: @Osvaldo: I repaired it. Now the big image (http://www.regensburgerturmtheater.de/wp-content/uploads/Mei.jpg) is provided again. The object debugger now says it is too small (Last time, it said nothing), but as you can see it isn't.

Comment: OK, I got no errors anymore. But still no big image.

Comment: You must use de debugger again to clean the cache. And even after that it may take two hours or more. Don't forget to check the new image has a diff filename.

Comment: Makes no difference. This is frustrating... Is it neccessary, that the images have exactly the 1.91:1 Aspect Ratio?

Comment: Try a smaller image maybe, that's massive to be using as an open graph image.

Comment: I already tried that. And as I said: Facebook HAS the large image. It just doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to force Facebook to show an image in a specific size in the news feed.   Facebook does resize images to fit in the news feed.   If they are using the correct image from your site, you have done all you can do.   It is then up to Facebook to determine how large they are willing to show it.

Comment: I found another similar question. Manually sharing the page often leads to different outcomes. In my case that worked.